# hacer que el usuario guarde un formulario para completar despues

Tags: php, html5, formularios

tengo un formulario (cuestionario) en php para que los clientes lo completen. El tema es que me gustaria que si no puede terminar de completarlo pueda guardarlo con las respuesta que ya contesto para terminar despues y enviarlo cuando este listo en su totalidad.
Eso es posible? de manera relativamente simple... ya que soy nueva en esto de los formularios.

Paso fragmento para que vean lo que tengo de base para el formulario

```html
<div id="contact_form">
  <form action="../confFormulario3.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="fecha" class="boton" name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha de hoy">
    <input type="text" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Email de la empresa">
    <div class="empresa">
      <h4 class="titulos">Datos de la empresa:</h4>
      <p class="preguntas">Define tu empresa con 3 palabras ó frase corta</p>
      <input type="text" id="define1" class="brief boton" name="define1" placeholder="Primera">
      <input type="text" id="define2" class="brief boton" name="define2" placeholder="Segunda">
      <input type="text" id="define3" class="brief boton" name="define3" placeholder="Tercera">
      <p class="preguntas">Cuáles son los valores o filosofía de tu empresa?</p>
      <textarea name="segunda" id="segunda" class="textarea boton" placeholder=""></textarea>
      <p class="preguntas">Qué imagen te gustaría transmitir, cómo te gustaría que te vieran tus clientes?</p>
      <textarea name="tercera" id="tercera" class="textarea boton" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="buttonEnviar" class="boton" value="ENVIAR">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrías crear un proceso que guarde cada X segundos (30 por ejemplo) toda la información de los formularios en LocalStorage. Se trata de un recurso que permite que le navegador nos almacene información de manera relativamente persistente. Lo único que tendrías que hacer después es, que si al cargar la página del formulario LocalStorage contiene datos para el formulario insertarlos para que el usuario continúe donde se quedó. https://deideaaapp.org/uso-del-localstorage-utilizando-html5-css3-jquery-e-ionic/

Comment: muchas gracias @phpMyGuel, es justo lo que estoy buscando. estuve viendo el enlace que me pasaste y veo como funciona y es lo que necesito. Lo que no tengo idea de como implementar es 1º lo del autoguardado y 2º que se abra con los datos guardados cuando el usuario vuelva a abrir el formulario para terminar de completarlo.... Si pudieras orientarme un poco (con el codigo) que hace estas acciones, te agradeceria muchisimo. El resto esta super explicado en el tutorial que me pasaste.

Answer (score 2):

Todo este proceso podría ejecutarse totalmente del lado del cliente, por lo que **PHP** no entraría en juego, solamente Javascript.

Primero crearía una función `setInterval()` que recogiese el valor de los campos de tu formulario cada **X** segundos:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  //Aquí debes programar la recogida de datos de tu formulario, tienes tutoriales en internet para ver como hacerlo con Javascript o Jquery para seguidamente subirlos a LocalStorage.
}, 30000);
```

Con eso ya tendrías los datos almacenados en el navegador. Ahora te faltaría recuperarlos al cargar la página donde tienes el formulario. Para ello podrías usar la función `$(document).ready()` (es de Jquery, existe su equivalente en Javascript básico, por si no quieres usar Jquery) que se lanza cuando carga el **DOM** para recuperar los datos de LocalStorage y rellenar los `<input>` con ellos.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Aquí recuperarías el contenido de LocalStorage para insertarlo en los campos de tu formulario.
});
```

No habría que olvidar el vaciar LocalStorage tras enviar el formulario, para que si el usuario quiere volver a enviar otro formulario no se le autocomplete con los datos del anterior.

**Referencias:** [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), [ready()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp)

Comment: buenisimo, lo pruebo y te comento como me fue